# Hadoop map reduce after migration Hbase 0.94.12 to 1.4.2

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to upgrade Hbase from 0.94.15 to a newer one, for example 1.4.2.
I'm trying to understand how much code it will affect and trying to change dependencies.

When I use dependency **org.apache.hbase:hbase:0.94.12** there is a package

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce
```

But when I try to upgrage to 1.4.2 (or 1.2.6) I can't find this package.
I've tried

```
org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.4.2
org.apache.hbase:hbase:1.4.2
org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop2-compat:1.4.2
```

But all unsuccessfully.

I use **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob** to initialize mappers and reducers **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper** to extends in mappers and so on.

Are these classes deprecated and there are another approaches or there is a dependency which contains this package?

**Update**
Dependency org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:1.4.2 helps. All code is compatible.

Comment: It is compiled with  org.apache.hbase:hbase-mapreduce:2.0.0-beta-2 but I really don't like the version number. Is it compatible?

Comment: https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html - The `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce` do exist.